How to check if key is in JSON sqlachemy
I am trying to select a segment if:

settings dict is not null
Has key user_parameters in it
And user_parameters (dict) has key user_id in it

Code below:
user_id = '100952'
select([self.db.segments]).where(
    and_(
        self.db.segments.c.settings.isnot(None),
        cast(self.db.segments.c.settings, JSON)["user_parameters"].as_string().contains(f"'{user_id}'"),
    )
)

Converting JSON to a string and searching for user_id in that string is not reliable, as it does not ensure that the captured string will be a key; it may also match a value. What is the correct way to check if user_id exists as a key in the settings['user_parameters'] dictionary?

You could use jsonb_path_exists.
I haven't tested the example, but it should look like this:
from sqlalchemy import func


select([self.db.segments]).where(
    and_(
        self.db.segments.c.settings.isnot(None),
        func.jsonb_path_exists(self.db.segments.c.settings, f'$.user_parameters.{user_id}')
    )
)

More info in the sqlalchemy docs and json functions in postgres.

Does not work. and user_id is a variable outside which I am trying to check if exists in that dictionary

Do you mean the user_id is a key inside user_parameters? Then see updated answer

This should work:
from sqlalchemy import select, and_, cast
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSONB, jsonb_path_exists

query = select([self.db.segments]).where(
    and_(
        self.db.segments.c.settings.isnot(None),
        jsonb_path_exists(
            cast(self.db.segments.c.settings, JSONB),
            f'$.user_parameters.{user_id}'
        )
    )
)


